# Early '90s horror/thriller movie/tv show - guy's head and arm trapped by closing electric car window

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

From a young age, early nineties, I've always remembered quite vividly a couple of scenes from what I 'think' was a movie (I was young so could have made it up although that's unlikely as it scared the crap out of me!)

First scene:

> A boy is in a room with candles which are all lit. I think he was dressed up in outdoor clothes such as a coat and hat. He sees a fairly old woman at the top of a set of stairs. A guy pops up behind her and strangles her (with a wire or something).

Second scene:

> The boy runs into a car and locks himself in but the window of one side is open. Just as he begins to close it, the same guy runs up and sticks his head and arm inside. The window keeps going up (I guess it's electronic windows) and the glass begins to break.

It's in colour, seems and felt like a horror or thriller but could very well have been a comedy! I'm sure i saw it before 1994. I've had these images in my head for over 20 years wondering where it's from so hopefully the community can put my mind at ease.

Comment: I chose the more memorable scene for the title.  Please edit if you can improve, but its useful to have something from the movie to jog memories.

Comment: @iandotkelly - Awesome, many thanks for the edit. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description reminds me maybe of **Lady in White** (1988).

There is a house full of candles.  And there is a scene where the kid is in a car and the bad guy is trying to get him...I think it is maybe an automatic tailgate window that catches him.

[image: LW]

Comment: 100% *Lady in White*. Both scenes are there.

Comment: @Walt - Agreed, saw some clips online and this it. Only question is: do I dare relive my childhood nightmare by watching all of it...?

Comment: I have the DVD, and because of this discussion I got it out to watch again.  You know, the version for TV was bowdlerized.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar - I see that quite often with moves on tv compared to their DVD counterparts. Thanks for noticing that, I will definitely try to get the DVD for this.